# Append appropriate columns between two sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If I have one sheet (Lookup) with the following columns:

ID, Region, Sub region, Population

Then another sheet (Month_Data) with the columns: Year, ID, Name, Winner, Wins

What does it mean I am asked to "append appropriate columns from the Lookup sheet to the Month_data sheet?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't you direct this question to the person that asked you this?

Comment: It means that you will add the columns `Region, Sub region, Population` to the right of the `Wins` column, and use `VLOOKUP` or `INDEX/MATCH` formulas to fill the new columns, e.g. in `F2` of `Month_Data` you could use the formula `=VLOOKUP($B2,Lookup!$A$2:B$100,2,False)` and copy it to cells `G2` and `H2` replacing the 2 with 3 and 4 and copy down all three cells.

Comment: While I agree with VBAsic2008, I think the main point is findwindow's point.  this isn't really a question for this forum and probably should be directed to whoever you're doing this for

Comment: @VBasic2008 I used an xLOOKUP

Answer (score -1):

It cannot mean to append beneath as the two tables have different column headings (different number of columns) - so it probably refers to a left join (or union) using ID as a common fiel and lookup - i.e. the final table would probably comprise 8 columns (ID being common so need not be replicated).

I'm only guessing here  as you haven't provided sample/example data / screenshot etc. to make a more informed guess...

(PS- use index as opposed to vlookup - more versatile as it can reference / lookup columns to the right or left of the lookup value)